# How many percentage of people still using ldpi devices?

Tags: android, icons, dpi

I am using some icons from Material Icons site by google. They provided the icon from mdpi to xxxhdpi. What about the ldpi devices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of devices in active use and using the Play Store, you can find out the breakdown of screen sizes and densities in [the device dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), updated monthly. The December 2016 edition of the dashboards shows 1.5% of devices are `ldpi` devices.

If you do not ship `ldpi` artwork, Android will down-sample some other density (e.g., `mdpi`). You may wish to test your icons on `ldpi` hardware to see how your icons look, and ship your own `ldpi` replacement for those icons that do not down-sample well.